# Automatically populate() on Mongoose document fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to automatically run populate() for referenced subdocuments for a particular model?

I have a City model that has referenced Region and Country documents that I would like to be automatically populated when a city/cities are fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there aren't docs for this in the Mongoose website; what I do is something like this:

```
schema.statics.createQuery = function( populates ) {
   var query = this.find();
   populates.forEach(function( p ) {
       query.populate( p );
   });

   return query;
};
```

Of course, there is validation and some other stuff in this method, but essentially it's what I do with my models.

In your case, you could hard code the populates in such a method, if you strictly need them in every find call.

Comment: That's definitely an interesting way to do it and works for top level finds, I'm curious if there's a way that would work for nested ref fetching. For example, I also have a model called Business that has an address field, and a reference to City. I would also like it so when Businesses are fetched, it populates City automatically, which in turn would automatically populate Region and Country as in the original question.

Comment: I haven't tested it very well yet, but what you could do is call `populate()` on each document instance after you have 'em. But beware that this may be more expensive than you're really needing.

Comment: I am loving MongoDB and Mongoose and Node.js but doesn't it seem like there are a lot of extra queries going on here? I did MySQL a lot before and there is just a join happening and a single round trip. I hope there is something MongoDB can do internally to fix this.

Comment: Let's see, but as of v2.4 there's no such thing yet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to auto-populate all references to another model out of the box (there are plugins though). In a similar fashion to @gustavohenke's answer you can use a static, along with a small change to your find query.

Here's what I'd do:

```
citySchema.statics.fieldsToPopulate = function() {
   return ['regionField', 'countryField'];
};
```

Where `regionField` and `countryField` are the fields which reference the models `Region` and `Country` respectively.

Then in your query you could populate accordingly:

```
var populate = city.fieldsToPopulate ? city.fieldsToPopulate() : [];

city.findById(id)
   .populate(populate)
   .exec(function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        res.render('template', { city: data });
      }
    });
```